# How can I change the interior and exterior borders separately in leaflet Polygon with a hole

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Is there any way to change the inner and outer line styles of a polygon/multipolygon with a hole?

I'm using **leaflet** and **l.geoJson**.

I found this example but the line style remains same for both interior and exterior borders if you change the  style color.

```
"style": {
    color: "black",
    opacity: 1,
    fillColor: "white",
    fillOpacity: 1
 }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/erictheise/VaGy5/)

Comment: You should insert the relevant code here directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the inner and outer line styles of a polygon/multipolygon with a hole?

No.

What you can do, however, is extract the outer ring and the inner rings beforehand. Then, use only a fill style for the polygon, a line style for the outer ring, and a different line style for the inner rings.

Comment: I dont know how to extract the the outer ring of multipolygon. Do you have any tips?

Comment: It's quite trivial - in the coordinates of every GeoJSON polygon, the first component is the outer ring and any other components are inner rings. For multipolygons, just iterate inside each polygon and follow the same logic. The webpage at http://mapsam.com/geojson-ring-visual/ illustrates this concept quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this without hacks. In case the shape is rendered using SVG, using a single `<g>` (example from [this geojson.io link](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:anonymous/b5f1174005ffdbd65bf3bbb235269718&map=4/68.12/63.54)):

```
<path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#555555" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" fill="#555555" fill-opacity="0.5" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M340 -145L388 455L640 451L812 291zM437 230L628 258L602 331L537 370z"></path>
```

If you really need to have different colors for the inner edges, I think you should extract the inner rings from the shapes and add polygons with the correct line color without a fill. This approach will not work if you want to have your borders to be transparant, because the original border will show through.